# LDAP/AD query to get company users

Tags: active-directory, ldap

i have a tree like this in the left frame

```
AD
Saved Queries
me.local
  Builtin
  Computers
  ...
  CompanyName
    computers
    contacts
    disabled
    distribution
    ....
    user
```

i'd like to get all *users* from user folder.

the content of the userfolder in the right frame is like this:

NAME                     TYPE
name1, surname1          user
name2, surname2          user
GROUP1                   security group
name3, surname3          user
name4, surname4          user
name5, surname5          user
...

i think the difference between cn and ou is not clear for me.
i have tried like his:

```
(&ou=user,ou=CompanyName,dc=me,dc=local)
```

and get no results.

Comment: We will need more informations, like the real DIT (LDAP tree, with correct DN), example of entries, and what you try to achieve, because your filter is not correct, meaning the syntax is no correct and so will never work

Comment: Thank you Esteban. i've updated my description above. Maybe it helps more.

Comment: It is not a problem about `ou` or `cn`. The knowledge about how LDAP directories works is the basic problem here. There are objects organized as a tree with branches which contains object and/or other branches, and so on and so forth. If you want all the users directly under a branch, you have to specify the `baseDN` of your search on this specific branch, and filter on an attribute common to all the object you want to retrieve, ie. for user is could be `(objectClass=user)`, the basedn here should be : `ou=user,ou=CompanyName,dc=me,dc=local`

Answer (score 0):

Specify a search dn or scope for your query and set it to your users ou

```
CN=Users,DC=YOUDOMAIN,DC=COM
```

If you want all the users the filter is simple. Here for AD:

```
(objectClass=organizationalPerson)
```

Depending on how your LDAP / AD is set up you would need to be authenticated to do LDAP queries. So create a user with read only rights, and test again.

To the question cn and ou:

The simplest (and not complety correct) way to put it, is that OU is a container (you can think of it as a folder) and cn should be a finaly entity (user, group, computer object, etc)

The problem is that in Microsoft's Active Directoy an CN can have subsidiary CN's. Therefore a CN is not always a leaf object.

Comment: if i try this - OU=user,OU=CompanyName,DC=me,DC=local - i get a empty answer / list. Here is a screenshot: [link](https://i.imgur.com/uLeoYtg.png). i need the list of users in folder "me.local -> CompanyName -> user". The whole thing should be for a nextcloud - login.

Comment: Try to change the OU=user to CN=user - For some reason Microsoft thought of the container user as an individual object rather than organizational unit. So the base search should be CN=user,OU=CompanyName,DC=me,DC=local

Comment: hello michael ... empty list only. i've no clue what i make wrong.

Comment: second thought: do you do this with an authentificated user or anonymous? See if there is an option to login to LDAP/AD and then do the search. If that also doees not help, please download the LDAP **Browser** from Softerra [link](http://www.ldapadministrator.com/download.htm). With this you can browse your AD and copy paste FDNs and also quickly test queries.

Comment: i use an authenticated user Michael. i'll try your link and be back soon.

Comment: with your software i created a "SELECT * FROM "OU=user,OU=CompanyName,DC=me,DC=local" SCOPE BASE" which shows the correct results. i take this to my nextcloud LDAP configuration and get no results. i'll take pen and paper in the next days.

Comment: now it gets a bit foggy... but nextcloud should ask with fields like "search DN", "Filter". you filter should be (objectClass=*), the search dn "OU=user,OU=CompanyName,DC=me,DC=local" But you already tried this.... maybe a silent SSL error? Try with and without SSL (LDAPS), after that I am blank without more info...  sorry

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you again. I'll try your ideas here. My NextCloud gets the Base DN automatically (dc=me,dc=local). The filter then is (objectclass=*) but its the wrong. I get over 200 Users but need just 12 or 13 from my (test) query(s) above.